# Trying to get sudoers working on openldap/centos7

Tags: centos7, openldap, sudo

I was following this tutorial here:

https://kifarunix.com/how-to-configure-sudo-via-openldap-server/

A lot of it made sense, but still new to openldap so some of this is cryptic too.  I have the openldap running with users authenticating on other machines even working with phpldapadmin.  So it was time to get sudoers working for some users.   I ran the `sudoers2ldif` command and got a file similar to what was showed in the tutorial, and edited it accordingly.  When It came time to run `ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f sudoers_modified.ldif` it failed with the error:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=defaults,ou=SUDOers,dc=apo,dc=local"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax
```

Is the 21, the line number of the .ldif file?  Or some other error code...also no idea what is invalid on the objectClass command...  posted is the ldif file below.

```
dn: cn=defaults,ou=SUDOers,dc=bbb,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: defaults
description: Default sudoOption's go here
sudoOption: !visiblepw
sudoOption: always_set_home
sudoOption: match_group_by_gid
sudoOption: always_query_group_plugin
sudoOption: env_reset
sudoOption: env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
sudoOption: env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
sudoOption: env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
sudoOption: env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
sudoOption: env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
sudoOption: secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

dn: cn=sudo,OU=SUDOers,dc=bbb,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: sudo
sudoUser: bobby
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAsUser: ALL
sudoCommand: ALL
```

Maybe sudoRole needs to be added somehow?  The other ldif I added successfully for this was:

```
dn: ou=SUDOers,dc=bbb,dc=local
objectCLass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: SUDOers
description: BBB SUDOers container
```

I had found another tutorial here:

https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=73807

With similar information slightly different, I didn't use this one because one of the ldif files that was posted had a ton of stuff that said it was 'autogenerated' and I had no idea how or where it came from.

After the one answer, I believe the file showed on the above link that has the data:

```
vi /testfolder/sudoers.ldif
#------------------------
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 b181185c
dn: cn=sudoers,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: sudoers
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.1 NAME 'sudoUser' DESC 'User(s
) who may run sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5Substrin
gsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.2 NAME 'sudoHost' DESC 'Host(s
) who may run sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5Substring
sMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.3 NAME 'sudoCommand' DESC 'Com
mand(s) to be executed by sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4
.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.4 NAME 'sudoRunAs' DESC 'User(
s) impersonated by sudo (deprecated)' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3
.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.5 NAME 'sudoOption' DESC 'Opti
ons(s) followed by sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466
.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.6 NAME 'sudoRunAsUser' DESC 'U
ser(s) impersonated by sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.
1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.7 NAME 'sudoRunAsGroup' DESC '
Group(s) impersonated by sudo' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.
1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.8 NAME 'sudoNotBefore' DESC 'S
tart of time interval for which the entry is valid' EQUALITY generalizedTim
eMatch ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.12
1.1.24 )
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.9 NAME 'sudoNotAfter' DESC 'En
d of time interval for which the entry is valid' EQUALITY generalizedTimeMa
tch ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1
.24 )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.1.10 NAME 'sudoOrder' DESC 'an i
nteger to order the sudoRole entries' EQUALITY integerMatch ORDERING intege
rOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15953.9.2.1 NAME 'sudoRole' DESC 'Sudoer
Entries' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( sudoUser $ sudoHost $ sudoCommand
$ sudoRunAs $ sudoRunAsUser $ sudoRunAsGroup $ sudoOption $ sudoOrder $ su
doNotBefore $ sudoNotAfter $ description ) )
```

Once I realized the file was the schema I added it and finally got this all working so in a round about way I accepted the answer even though I had to dig into what I was doing a bit more.  Btw the schema file wasn't used in my ldap I had to add it via the ldapadd

Comment: You're using the dynamic config for openldap rather than slapd.conf and associated *.schema files. The server config is accessed via ldap and you can view it with `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -d "cn=config" ldapi:///` it seems like the tutorial you were following just relies on the fact that the sudo schema was already incorporated into the ldap server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the 21, the line number of the .ldif file? Or some other error code

That's the return code for Invalid Syntax.

```
LDAP_INVALID_SYNTAX - 21 (0x15)
An attribute value specified on an LDAP client request does not have a valid syntax specified. 
For example, if an attribute type in the schema has an integer syntax, an integer value must be specified on an add or modify request.
```

Can you do the following to troubleshoot this further ?

- Check whether sudoers schema files are present on the host. if it's not present, copy it from [here](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html)

  ```
  # ls -l /etc/openldap/schema/sudo.schema
  ```
- Check whether the sudo.schema (or equivalent file) is added to the relevant openldap server configuration file.

  ```
  # grep sudo.schema /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
  include         /etc/openldap/schema/sudo.schema
  ```
- Check if sudoers OU exists!

  ```
  # ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -x -LLL -s one -b "OU=SUDOers,dc=bbb,dc=local"
  ```

  If it's not, add it using ldapadd (1)
- Check if there are syntax errors in the ldif file using

  ```
  # /usr/bin/cvtsudoers /tmp/sample.ldif -i ldif -f sudoers
  ```

You should probably go through the official sudo documentation [link](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html) that contain explanations for some of the above thing.

Comment: I noticed I do not have a slapd.conf at all, but I think it is because that was deprecated and I am running a new version?

Comment: Since you are using centos, can you check the version of openldap that you are running now using something like this `rpm -qi openldap-servers` ?